# I am trying to create a project with Unreal Engine, but an error pops up and the project is not created

Tags: .net, unreal-engine5

The error was this.

```
Running C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_5.0/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool/UnrealBuildTool.exe  -projectfiles -project="C:/Users/Person/Documents/Unreal Projects/Testing/Testing.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
A fatal error occurred. The required library hostfxr.dll could not be 
found.
If this is a self-contained application, that library should exist in [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.0\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\].
If this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in the global location [C:\Program Files\dotnet\] or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable to specify the runtime location or register the runtime location in [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\InstallLocation].
```

The .NET Core runtime can be found at:

```
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have Visual Studio installed (19 or 22) with these?

Workloads:

- .NET desktop development
- Desktop development with C++
- Game development with C++

Components:

- .NET Framework 4.6.2 SDK
- .NET Core 3.1 (LTS)
- Windows 10 SDK
- MSVC v142 - C++ Compiler x64/x86

In your case the UnrealBuildTool asks for `.NET Core 3.1` but you can just download and configurate whole VS with the stuff I've listed.
It should avoid the confusion in the future.